How to remove inactive devices when scanning for Bluetooth devices using PyBluez?
I'm developing a Python application to scan for nearby Bluetooth devices using PyBluez. I'm using the discover_devices function to discover devices within a certain duration, and I've set lookup_names and lookup_class parameters to True to retrieve the device names and class information.
However, I've noticed that the scan results include inactive devices that I've connected to before. These inactive devices clutter the scan results and make it harder to identify currently available devices.
Is there a way to filter out or remove inactive devices from the scan results in PyBluez? I'd like to only display devices that are currently active and available for connection.
Here is my code simply code
import Bluetooth
def discover_devices(self):
    nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(duration=5, lookup_names=True, lookup_class=True)
    return nearby_devices


"This project is not under development". Perhaps try another library.

I'm using pybluez2 as I know it works @Kate

discover_devices has this argument: "flush_cache - return devices discovered in previous inquiries". Source code here. Surely this can help?

@Kate yeah I tested and it's still same

Could it be that there is a bug elsewhere in your code? Your function discover_devices is part of a class, so perhaps there is something wrong with instantiation and you are fetching stale results.

@Kate I don't think I'm using in flet  and I'm just calling that and I'm getting all devices names which I connected before.
